# How put url to another page in css

Tags: html, css

I need to put a link to another page in my h2 element. I don't want use href but I need to do this with css
Suppose to have this:

```
  <h2 class="path">Edizione</h2>
```

And in my css

```
   . path {
    url: 'https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp';
    }
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: You can't. You need to use HTML or javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but you can't do this with CSS. Also, I'm pretty sure href is for the `<a>` tag.

If you want your `<h2>` to be a link, either wrap it with an `<a>` tag, or put the `<a>` tag inside it, like this:

```html
<a href="path.html"><h2>link</h2></a>
<h2><a href="path.html">link</a></h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS Doesn't let you do redirects, instead try using JavaScript's built in [Window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location) method. If you have an even binding for an (onClick) event simply add this code inside of the callback and your page will re-direct to the url provided.

`Window.location = 'https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp';`